# SQL Error no Postgres

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Meu select:

```
SELECT * (
          SELECT  v.placa FROM gr_veiculo v WHERE v.id = (
                 SELECT DISTINCT r.cavalo FROM lg_relacao_veiculo r 
                 WHERE (
                   r.cavalo   = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
                   r.carreta1 = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
                   r.carreta2 = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
                 ) and r.cavalo is not null
          )
        ) AS placa,       
       sm.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_status_os_id AS status,
       sm.atendimento_id

FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao sm
INNER JOIN mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo x
      ON x.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id
WHERE sm.concessionaria_id = 15 and sm.ativo = true AND x.ativo = TRUE
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
SQL Error: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Comment: Qual o resulyado da query: `SELECT DISTINCT r.cavalo FROM lg_relacao_veiculo r 
WHERE (r.cavalo   = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
... OR
       r.carreta2 = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
      ) AND r.cavalo is not null
`? Um único cavalo? (Omitido parte pois excedeu o tamanho do comentário).

Comment: O que está acontecendo é que tua subquery ta retornando mais de um registro, nessa parte: WHERE v.id = ( SELECT DISTINCT r.cavalo FROM lg_relacao_veiculo r (...), é como se você estivesse tentando verificar se 1informação é igual a uma lista de informações (v.id = subquery que retorna varias coisas). O que precisa ser pensado é "só deveria retornar um registro mesmo?" se sim, voce precisa ajustar a subquery para que isto ocorra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está nesse trecho:

```
WHERE v.id = (
                 SELECT DISTINCT r.cavalo FROM lg_relacao_veiculo r 
                 WHERE (
                   r.cavalo   = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
                   r.carreta1 = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) OR
                   r.carreta2 = (SELECT mv.gr_veiculo_id FROM mt_solicitacao_manutencao_veiculo mv WHERE mv.mt_solicitacao_manutencao_id = sm.id AND mv.ativo = TRUE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
                 ) and r.cavalo is not null
          )
```

O **Distinct** do Select não resolve o seu problema, pois esse seu select pode trazer mais de uma linha de resultado devido ao **OR**, o **Distinct** apenas tira os dados duplicados, você pode utilizar o **LIMIT 1** ordenando de forma decrescente para resolver o seu problema, mas é necessário verificar se esse é o resultado que você realmente deseja mostrar.